# Custom http request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a custom **POST HTTP request** in Jmeter , but when I run the script it shows request formed badly. I am taking that exact parameter as and header response, still, it is not executing.

Can anyone help? Is there any sequence to be maintained while entering names and values in HTTP header manager.

Comment: Copy this XML and save it as .jmx and open it in JMeter. I have modified few bits specific to my use case but this will guide you on setting up POST request. http://www.codesend.com/view/fad6a15e1051d8fbcba817469187f7e3/

Comment: Thank you , but where should i copy this , in word? I tried but i am not able to open it.

Comment: Open Notepad. Save content  to the file with name like "MyTest.jmx" and then open that file from JMeter.

Comment: Hi i tried it was working, but what to do is there are many names and parameters in POST request . Does the adding sequence matters?

Comment: Sequence of header parameters doesn't matter. If you want to learn details about it check this RFC. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 . Only time it matters when there are multiple comma separated values for a given field. For example Accept header can have multiple values like "Accept:text/xml,application/json" in this case text/xml has priority over application/json.